# Visual Studio Regular Expression Find and Replace

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to change this below using Regular Expression

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Common/Scripts/UserControls/Form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Common/Scripts/UserControls/Form.js")%>></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Find:

```
\<script type\=\"text\/javascript\" language\=\"javascript\" src="{[^"]+}"\>\<\/script\>
```

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~\1")%>></script>
```

The key things to note:

- You can match an expression for use in the replace section with braces `{}`.  I use `[^"]+` to capture all characters between the quotes - the `[]` matches a set of characters, where `^` means "not" - so `[^"]` matches anything *except* a quote.  Then `+` means match one or more (non-quote characters).
- Some characters have special meaning, so you can escape them with `\`.  You can safely escape most chracters that don't have meaning if you put an extra `\` unnecessarily in front of them, so I am overzealous just to be safe.
- Use `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, etc. to use captured groups in the replace expression.  So I'm using `\1` to refer to the `src` attribute value matched in the find.

Comment: I am new to this, actually i need to find 
src="/Common/Scripts/UserControls/Form.js"
and
Replace
="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Common/Scripts/UserControls/Form.js")%>